# PDAL works in Windows command but not in OSGeo4WShell?

Tags: postgresql, lidar, osgeo4w, shell, pdal

I want to import a pointcloud into a PostGIS database. AFAIK you accomplish this with PDAL which comes with OSGeo4W.

I was following this tutorial: [OSGeo4W LiDAR tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/)
and also this tutorial [PDAL.io tutorial](https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/info/single-point.html).
Both of them use the **osgeo4w Shell**, but for me the command 
    `pdal`
throws an error in the OSGeo4W Shell:

> Command is unknown or can't be found.

When I execute any command in cmd.exe the `pdal` command seems to work.

Can anyone explain why this is?

I want to understand this properly to avoid any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The OSGeo4W shell sets up its own environmental variables at launch. So its own Python paths and other paths. This allows it to work even in complex environments with other software like ArcGIS installed on the computer.

I would guess that you did not install PDAL through the OSGeo4W shell?

Install it through there and the command should work. Or just run it through the regular command line. Or provide a full path to the PDAL.exe file when running it.